# Write the output in another file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm using LDA to find topics in a text.

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation

n_components = 5
n_top_words = 10


def print_top_words(model, feature_names, n_top_words):
    for topic_idx, topic in enumerate(model.components_):
        message = "Topic %d: " % topic_idx
        message += " ".join([feature_names[i]
                         for i in topic.argsort()[:-n_top_words - 1:-1]])
        print(message)
    print()

df = pandas.read_csv('text.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
text = df['a']
data_samples = text.values.tolist()

# Use tf (raw term count) features for LDA.
tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(data_samples)


lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=n_components, max_iter=5,
                            learning_method='online',
                            learning_offset=50.,
                            random_state=0)
lda.fit(tf)

print("\nTopics in LDA model:")
tf_feature_names = tf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
print_top_words(lda, tf_feature_names, n_top_words)
```

I have a good output:

> Topics in LDA model:
>
> Topic 0: order not produced well received advance return always wishes
>
> Topic 1: then wood color between pay broken transfer change arrival bad
>
> Topic 2: delivery product possible package store advance date broken very good
>
> Topic 3: misleading product france model broken open book year research association
>
> Topic 4: address delivery change invoice deliver missing please billing advance change

But I wish write this output in a csv file with pandas.

```
Topic 0   Topic 1   Topic 2   ...
order     advance   ...       ...
not       return    ...       ...
produced  always    ...       ...
well      wishes    ...       ...
received  hello     ...       ...
```

It's possible?

Comment: use `df.to_csv('file.csv')`

Comment: how is this output generated? is it dataFrame?\

Comment: No, they're just lines. So I have doubts if I can use pandas.

Comment: can you store this output as string?

Comment: Yes, I think. I can do 
topics = print_top_words(lda, tf_feature_names, n_top_words)

Comment: make a list of lists and then transform it into pandas data frame. ex: [['Topic 0', 'order', 'not', 'produced', 'well', 'received'],[]...[]] and use pd.DataFrame(list).T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def print_top_words(model, feature_names, n_top_words):
    out_list = []
    for topic_idx, topic in enumerate(model.components_):
        message = "Topic%d: " % topic_idx
        message += " ".join([feature_names[i]
                     for i in topic.argsort()[:-n_top_words - 1:-1]])
        out_list.append(message.split())
        print(message)
    print()
    return outlist
...
df_ = print_top_words(lda, tf_feature_names, n_top_words)
df_ = pd.DataFrame(df_).T
df_.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Topics in LDA model:

Topic 0: order not produced well received advance return always wishes

Topic 1: then wood color between pay broken transfer change arrival bad

Topic 2: delivery product possible package store advance date broken very good

Topic 3: misleading product france model broken open book year research association

Topic 4: address delivery change invoice deliver missing please billing advance change

`df.to_csv("filename.csv")`